# Run Java application in Android OS devices

Tags: java, android, spring, jar, apk

I have an application Java developped using intellij and now I should make it working in Anrdoid device.
Is there any possibility to run a jar java application inside Android Devices?
or to compile a java project to both jar and apk?
Thank you

Comment: Does your application have any UI?

Comment: No, it is just an API service